# What is the point of data augmentation?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

The code below is based on François Collet. He uses it to show that when the training set is small (2000 images), data augmentation improves the classification power in the validation set (which is true!).

My questions are:

If the **model.fit_generator** method uses **steps_per_epoch = 2000 // batch_size**. Are we using 2000 images per epoch?

If yes. What is the point of data augmentation if I use an augmented sample size equal in size to the original one?

```
batch_size = 32

# Train data augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale = 1./255,
        shear_range = 0.2,
        zoom_range = 0.2,
        horizontal_flip = True)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size = (150, 150),
        batch_size = batch_size,
        class_mode = 'binary')


# Train data generation
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size = (150, 150),
        batch_size = 20,
        class_mode = 'binary')


# training and validation
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch = 2000 // batch_size,
                              epochs = 100,
                              validation_data = validation_generator,
                              validation_steps = 500 // batch_size)
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that you posted is quite dated, but serves the purpose for the explanation.

Admittedly we have `2000` images. We use them all, but the number of steps that are performed in that epoch is `2000//batch_size`, since you update the weights of the network after a batch of size `batch_size`. Therefore you perform `2000//batch_size` steps.

At the same time, think about **augmentation as enrichment at run-time**. When we use augmentation you do not create new examples which are physically stored on your drive, but when you load the batch into the memory. This means that, out of the batch that contains `batch_size` elements, some of them are modified(augmented), and fed into your network. Each augmentation has a probability associated, that is there is `N %` probability (you can set it even manually if you want) that your image is subjected to that specific augmentation.

But this means that as the training progresses, as the number of epochs increase, your network gets to see many more images than the initial size of 2000.

Comment: It seams that when we use data augmentation epochs serves a dual purpose. The original purpose, that states how many times we want to use the training sample to adjust the model.
The new purpose, since, in each epoch, a new (augmented) training set is generated, epochs now also defines how many different/augmented samples we will use to train the model.

Comment: It serves only the second purpose that you have stated. 2000//batch_size has nothing to do with augmentation, it is how to define training steps in Keras.

Answer (score 1):

In the snippet that you have provided, `steps_per_epoch = 2000 // batch_size` essentially means that the model will see the whole 2000 images during an epoch but out of those 2000 images many of them will be replaced with their augmented counterparts based on either a specific probability that you can provide or by randomly choosing the images.

For eg. Consider you are building a Dog-vs-Cats classifier and the dataset is made up of images of right-facing dogs and left-facing cats only. In this case, if you don't apply augmentation (horizontal_flipping) then the model might learn that `all the left facing animals are cats` which will lead to incorrect results when given an image of a left-facing dog.
Augmentation here (specifically horizontal_flipping) will randomly flip the images of cats and dogs enabling the model to reach a better solution and hence make it more robust!

**Augmentation Happens in-place no new images are generated.**